# Prove that the functional series is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Prove that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1 + x + x ^ 2 + \dots + x ^ {n ^ 2}} $$
is continuous on $[0;1)\cup(1;+\infty)$.

I've managed to do it for $x > 1$ by showing that $ \frac{x^n}{1 + x + x ^ 2 + \dots + x ^ {n ^ 2}} = \frac{x^n(x-1)}{x^{n^2+1}-1} < \frac{2}{n^2} $ and using Weierstrass M-test for uniform convergence. The hardest part is to show that it's continuous on $[0; 1)$ because it's uniformly convergent on $[0; a)$, where $a<1$, but not on $[0; 1)$. All proofs of continuity of series like this that I found start with proving uniform convergence but here it's not the case. How should I go about proving this statement?

Comment: Well, because of what you said you have uniform convergence on compact subsets of $[0,1)$, therefore the limit is continuous on $[0,1)$. The truly hardest part is proving continuity at $1$, specifically on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ \ f(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^{n^2}}$

We can write that:
$\forall x \in [0,1) \ , \ f(x)= \dfrac{x}{1+x} +\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\dfrac{x^n(1-x)}{1-x^{n^2+1}}\geqslant \dfrac{x}{1+x}+\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}x^n(1-x)$

$\forall x \in [0,1)\ , \ f(x)\geqslant \dfrac{x}{1+x} +x^2$

---

Suppose $f$ continuous at $x_0=1$. Then:

$f(1) \geqslant \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}+x^2\right) =\dfrac{3}{2}$

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}\geqslant \dfrac{3}{2}\ \ $ and it's easy to see that this inequality is false.

---

So, $f$ is not continuous at $x_0=1$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path : thanks

Comment: Also, you are taking the limit as x approaches 1 from the left, so the function is only discontinuous from the left.